# How to see if url is mobile only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following script: http://jsfiddle.net/q7pjfyxu/

script:

```
function addhttp(url) {
   if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\/[mM]\./i.test(url)) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

alert(addhttp("https://m.mysite.com/"));
```

I would like to get different variation:

```
// - https://m.
// - http://m.
// - https://www.m.
// - http://www.m.
```

It's not working at the moment...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using this for, but this naming convention is rare these days.

Comment: `if (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?m\./i.test(url))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an optional group for the `www.` part:

`^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?m\.`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fhvo7T/1)

You might also make the first capturing group a non capturing group `(?:`.

You could shorten the if / else because [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns a boolean:

```
return (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?m\./i.test(url));
```

```js
const strings = [
  "https://m.",
  "http://m.",
  "https://www.m.",
  "http://www.m."
];
strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(addhttp(s));
});

function addhttp(url) {
  return (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?m\./i.test(url));
}
```

Comment: @Si8 You are already using `i` flag, no need using `[mM]`, just `m` will do.